# quill_html_editor crashes when fetching some data from firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, quill

I've built a news page which uses quill_html_editor as a rich text editor, saves data to firestore database. saving data works perfect, all good there.

however if one tries to edit a post that had any rich text in it (bold, italic, anything), it completely crashes the website. This is only the case on web deploy and works fine in debug.

my guess is i'm displaying the data wrong somehow? code as follows:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: postInfo.snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 1,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final post = snapshot.data!.docs[index];

            final content = post["content"];

            return ListView(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
              
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: constraints * .05),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            ToolBar(
                              toolBarColor: grey,
                              activeIconColor: black,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              iconSize: 20,
                              controller: quillController,
                              customButtons: [
                                InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {},
                                    child:
                                        const Icon(Icons.favorite)),
                                InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {},
                                    child:
                                        const Icon(Icons.add_circle)),
                              ],
                            ),
                            QuillHtmlEditor(
                              text: content,
                              hintText: 'Content',
                              controller: quillController,
                              isEnabled: true,
                              ensureVisible: false,
                              minHeight: 500,
                              autoFocus: false,
                              textStyle: _editorTextStyle,
                              hintTextStyle: _hintTextStyle,
                              hintTextAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 10, top: 10),
                              hintTextPadding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                              backgroundColor: _backgroundColor,
                              inputAction: InputAction.newline,
                              loadingBuilder: (context) {
                                return const Center(
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  strokeWidth: 1,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ));
                              },
                              onFocusChanged: (focus) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _hasFocus = focus;
                                });
                              },
                              onEditorCreated: () {
                                setHtmlText(content);
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                       ],
                  ),
                ),
               
              ],
            );
          });
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Error${snapshot.error}'),
      );
    } else {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
  },
),
```